# Error al ejecutar flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Mi error:

```
(flask_env) C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com>index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\index.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 624, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from markupsafe._compat import text_type, string_types, int_types, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe._compat'
```

Mi código:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return'Hola Mundo!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a instalar el módulo que te falta con la siguiente línea:

`pip install markupsafe`

Puedes deducir esto a partir de la última línea:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe._compat'`

Además, aunque no estoy 100% seguro de que sea necesario deberías sustituir `name`por `__name__` y `'main'` por `'__main__'`